# OpenSSL 1.1.1 with downwards compatible API (to 1.0.2)

Tags: openssl

Is there a way that I can use all the functions with OpenSSL 1.1.1 that I used in 1.0.2? I see that they made all the structs opaque, so I have to use getter and setter functions. But I want to avoid having to refactor my entire code basis. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean compatible with 1.0.2 not 1.1.0? No additional structures were made opaque between 1.1.0 and 1.1.1. Lots of structures were made opaque between 1.0.2 and 1.1.0

Comment: Yes, sorry. It was a typo. I meant between 1.0.2 and 1.1.0